# Does anyone know how I can replace a par of a string in a 2d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, 2d

I am trying to replace the white spaces in "board" with an "X" or "O" depending on what row and column the users provide as input without making each column a separate array.

```
board = [["   |   |   "],
         ["---|---|---"],
         ["   |   |   "],
         ["---|---|---"],
         ["   |   |   "]]
```

Comment: It would be better to use a GUI in your case, you can try learning tkinter, which a lot of people use to build these common tic tac toe projects, alternatively you could use pygame to build the UI

Comment: If you want to print the tic tac toe box directly on console, use multiple print statements inside a function to build the box and call that function whenever a player makes a move, This will make your job much easier.

Comment: Use list of list to create a matrix, or simply use a single list and print it in such a manner such that it resembles a 2d matrix.

Comment: @SauravSaha Thank you, I think I'll go with that.